# How can I transform an input into a shorter version with a prefix

Tags: javascript

Im setting up a custom JS transformation for some input in a file. The inputs are mobile phones, however in the variable "phone" they are either:
e.g.
412345678
0412345678/82269882

in the input file. I need to transform these into the variable "e_phone":
e.g.
+61412345678

I have attempted the below

Any ideas?

```
var phone ="412345678/82269882";
var prefix = "+61";
if (phone < 12) {
    var e_phone = prefix.concat(phone.substring(0, 9));
    } else {
    var e_phone = prefix.concat(phone.substring(1, 10);
}

return e_phone;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` by `/` and then add `prefix` using `map()`

```js
var phone ="412345678/82269882";
var prefix = "+61";
let res = phone.split('/').map(x => prefix + x);
console.log(res)
```